# Using a newline character with Core Data and displaying it properly in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitextview, ipod-touch

I'm storing a list of things in one string stored in a core data database.  For example.. the stored string would look like @"apple \n pear \n orange".  I'm using a UITextView to display the list and I want it to display like:

- apple
- pear
- orange

..but it just displays:
apple \n pear \n orange

Anyone know how to get it to honor the newline characters?
I'm setting the UITextView's text just like this.  list is equal to "apple \n pear \n orange"

```
myTextView.text = fruits.list;
```

Comment: Your stored string isn't escaping the newlines, by any chance? That is, make sure your stored string isn't actually: @"apple \\n pear \\n orange"

Comment: That's a good tip to check for... I'm pretty sure that actual newlines are respected by UILabel and UITextField. Make sure the content is exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because xcode takes "\n" as a literal string \n.
You have to have 2 \'s because the first is an escape character that will tell xcode that your \ is not a string. It looks like:

```
NSString @"apple \\n pear \\n orange";
```